# LaTeX Error: \begin{document} ended by \end{section}

Tags: sectioning

I am encountering the above error message. This is what I have so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\title{Assignment \#1}
\author{First Name Last Name}
\date{March 20, 2014}

\begin{document}
\maketitle     
\section*{Question 1}
\textit{Scenario containing 2 pirates :} \\*\\*
Regardless of how the gold is split, the 2nd pirate will vote against the 1st pirate and take all the gold. \\*\\*
\end{section}

\textit{Scenario containing 3 pirates:} 

\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{3 Pirates}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c c c}
\hline\hline
Pirate\#1 & Pirate\#2 & Pirate\#3 \\  
\hline
x & x &  x \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Comment: `\section` is a macro, not an environment.  Thus, `\end{section}` is incorrect.  remove it and the code compiles. Note: any `\end{}` must be matched with its corresponding `\begin{}`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). Thanks for composing a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that reproduced the problem.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes that seems like an answer to me! `:)`

Answer (score 9):

LaTeX provides two forms for executing content: the macro, and the environment.  Which is preferable depends on the use.  Which is available is often beyond your control.  Some commands are given in both forms, *e.g.*, `\centering` versus `\begin{center}...\end{center}`.

But the key usage difference is that a macro's arguments (if any) are provided at the time of invocation, whereas an environment is told to begin with a `\begin{environment-name}` statement and continues under the control of that environment's settings until an `\end{environment-name}` is invoked.  In this regard, the environment requires the symmetry of a `\begin{}...\end{}` "book-ends".

In your example, `\section` is a macro, not an environment.  That is to say, it did not begin with `\begin{section}`. When invoked, it produces a header to show the section title, it creates a number for the section, and it may make note of an entry for a table of contents.  The section header may be stylized in larger, bolder font, or in any number of ways, depending on how `\section` has been defined by the class and or included packages.  But once the argument(s) to `\section` have been processed, the subsequent text is not within the confines of a "section environment", but just regular document text.  `\section` has no more to do with it.

Thus, `\end{section}`, which appears in your MWE, is incorrect. Remove that line and the code compiles.