# LaTeX end section or subsection

Tags: sectioning

How can I specify the end of subsection. In my example:

[image]

I have a subsection with only 3 rows, but I see the next paragraph also as continuance of the subsection:

```
\subsection{Kontrolle}
Zur Kontrolle eines physischen Systems werden die Time Series, welche durch Sensoren produziert werden, ebenfalls analysiert, um die besonderen Ereignisse zu entdecken.\\\\
In der Time-Series-Analyse gibt es besondere Herausforderungen. Time Series haben üblicherweise eine enorme Größe. Jeder Zeitpunkt in einer Time Series ist eine Dimension, deswegen haben die Punkte in einer Time Series hohe dimensionale Räume. Z. B.  jeder Punkt in einer Time Series mit der Länge 1000 hat 1000 Dimensionen. Die Bearbeitung solcher Höhen dimensionaler Räume ist nicht einfach, sogar mit Super-Rechner.
Um darüber hinaus eine Time Series zu..
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165823/latex-error-begindocument-ended-by-endsection/.  a `\subsection` is a macro, not an environment.  What follows is just text.  If you need to start a new (sub)section, you have to issue an additional sectioning command.

Comment: I dont want to begin another subsection, I want to resume my section

Comment: why would not the next paragraph be assumed to be something other than part of the same section?  if you mean that you want to make sure it starts on the same page, you might end the first paragraph with `\par\nobreak`.

Comment: You don't provide enough information to fully understand your problem.  If you get what you hope, what visual clues will the reader have that you returned to the prior section?  A different indentation, for example?

Comment: Sorry, I am understanding your post now :) thanks

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but of relevance for creating a document that's taken seriously by your readers: There's an absolutely awful hyphenation instance of the word "Time" in the second paragraph of your posting. Please tell LaTeX *not* to hyphenate this word under any circumstance.

Comment: Similar questions have been asked before, for example http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117382/ http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48464/ http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129808/ http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170530/

Comment: Possibly Related: [Environments for visually setting text apart](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37245/environments-for-visually-setting-text-apart).

Comment: My $0.02: I think a document structure like that does nothing to contribute to clarity. Especially in a technical environment.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There is no real typographic tradition for marking going "up" to the parent section, traditional settings (and the latex markup) more or less assume that a section has some material at the start but once it starts subsection that all material will be in (some) subsection. So even if you changed the markup to be something like `\begin{subsection}...\end{subsection}` so in the source it was unambiguous, it is not clear that your readers would know unless you make the typesetting very explicit.

One way would be to use a form that does have a typographic structure which suggests nesting, and downgrade your subsubsections to a list.

If Kontrolle was the fourth `\item` in (say) a description or enumerate list, the paragraph after it would be (or could be) indented, and then the following unindented paragraph would be obviously returning to the main text.

Of course, you don't have to change the markup much you could arrange that subsections were indented (or boxed, or given a pink background or whatever works for you).